# declare cursor error on mysql "error in your SQL syntax"

Tags: mysql, database, cursor

please help here

```
delimiter $
create procedure corrige_preg()
begin
    declare var_test integer;
    declare var_contador integer;
    set var_contador = 1;
    select test_tnum into var_test from preg
    group by test_tnum having max(pnum)<>count(pnum);
    if var_test is null then
        select "ok";
    else
        declare var_cursor cursor for
        select pnum from preg where test_tnum = var_test;
        open var_cursor;
        loop1: loop
            fetch var_cursor into pnum;
            pnum = var_contador;
            set var_contador=var_contador+1;
        end loop loop1;
        close var_cursor;
    end if;
end $
```

> Error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'declare var_cursor cursor for       select pnum from preg where
>   test_tnum = var_test' at line 11

Comment: `declare` can only be used after `begin`, not after `else`.

Comment: still gives me the same error

Comment: Are you sure it was the same error? When I added `BEGIN`, I got different errors because of the undeclared variable `pnum`.

Comment: thanks, its was an other error ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the cursor declaration to the top, right after the variable declaration.

For example:

```
delimiter $
create procedure corrige_preg()
begin
    declare var_test integer;
    declare var_contador integer;
    declare var_pnum integer;

    declare var_cursor cursor for
    select pnum from preg where test_tnum = var_test;   

    set var_contador = 1;
    select test_tnum into var_test from preg
    group by test_tnum having max(pnum)<>count(pnum);
    if var_test is null then
        select "ok";
    else        
        open var_cursor;
        loop1: loop
            fetch var_cursor into var_pnum;
            -- var_pnum = var_contador;
            set var_contador=var_contador+1;
        end loop loop1;
        close var_cursor;
    end if;
end $
```

Answer (score 0):

Declarations have to be after `BEGIN`, so wrap a `BEGIN`/`END` block around the `ELSE` block. You also need a declaration for `pnum`, and have to use the `SET` statement to assign to it.

```
delimiter $
create procedure corrige_preg()
begin
    declare var_test integer;
    declare var_contador integer;
    set var_contador = 1;
    select test_tnum into var_test from preg
    group by test_tnum having max(pnum)<>count(pnum);
    if var_test is null then
        select "ok";
    else begin
        declare pnum integer;
        declare var_cursor cursor for
        select pnum from preg where test_tnum = var_test;
        open var_cursor;
        loop1: loop
            fetch var_cursor into pnum;
            set pnum = var_contador;
            set var_contador=var_contador+1;
        end loop loop1;
        close var_cursor;
    end;
    end if;
end $
delimiter ;
```